# Any ideas for ROLLBACK TRANSACTION on this SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, rollback

Can someone help me with this SQL statement. I run it on the SQL Server engine.

I have the following statement that removes all entries in the table and replaces them with new ones:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM [t1] WHERE [id]>10;
INSERT INTO [t1] ([id], [v2], [v3]) SELECT COALESCE(MAX([id]), 0)+1, 'a1', 'b1' FROM [t1];
INSERT INTO [t1] ([id], [v2], [v3]) SELECT COALESCE(MAX([id]), 0)+1, 'a2', 'b2' FROM [t1];
--and so on, I may have up to 100 of these inserts
INSERT INTO [t1] ([id], [v2], [v3]) SELECT COALESCE(MAX([id]), 0)+1, 'aN', 'bN' FROM [t1];
COMMIT;
SET XACT_ABORT OFF;
```

What I want to know is how do you use ROLLBACK in case the transaction above fails?

PS. I basically need to revert the database to what it used to be in case of any error in that statement above.

**EDIT:**
Updated with the SET XACT_ABORT ON; statement suggested below. Is it how it's supposed to look?

Comment: your usage of `XACT_ABORT` looks correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `SET XACT_ABORT ON` if you want the transaction to fully rollback on an error.

With this set to `ON`, if any of the statements fails, the transaction will rollback. You do not need to call `ROLLBACK` for that to happen.

Under this condition, the moment you use a `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, every statement will be part of that transaction, meaning they will all either work or all fail. If there is an error before the `COMMIT`, the transaction will rollback and you database will be at the same state it was as before `BEGIN TRANSACTION` (assuming no other clients are changing the database at the same time).

See the documentation for [`XACT_ABORT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx).

Comment: This is incorrect and dangerous a assumption. By default a transaction will not automatically rollback on insert failures.

Comment: @M_M - Can you link to documentation that state this?

Comment: @M_M - From what I can see in the documentation, there is nothing to support your claims. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx By default, `XACT_ABORT` is off. Only when `XACT_ABORT` is on will SQL Server behave the way you describe. Specifically I am referring to your comment that "if the statement fails, the transaction will rollback" Certainly an explicit transaction creates an all or nothing unit of work but you need to explicitly rollback or commit a transaction, unless you `SET XACT_ABORT ON`

Comment: Nice. Thank you, all. So the bottom line, I need to add SET XACT_ABORT ON; up front before BEGIN TRANSACTION, right? Shall I also reset it back to OFF after COMMIT?

Comment: @ahmd0 - Correct, you should set it to `ON` before starting the transaction. Setting it back to `OFF` would be good practice.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the original post. Also, can you please explain this, "assuming no other clients are changing the database at the same time"? I thought BEGIN/COMMIT TRANSACTION makes it execute atomically within that block. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 4):

@Oded has covered an good approach to handle your rollback automatically. For completeness, I'll give you another method to handle that situation explicitly using [try catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx).

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRY
    DELETE FROM [t1] WHERE [id]>10;
    INSERT INTO [t1] ([id], [v2], [v3]) SELECT COALESCE(MAX([id]), 0)+1, 'a1', 'b1' FROM [t1];
    INSERT INTO [t1] ([id], [v2], [v3]) SELECT COALESCE(MAX([id]), 0)+1, 'a2', 'b2' FROM [t1];
    --and so on, I may have up to 100 of these inserts
    INSERT INTO [t1] ([id], [v2], [v3]) SELECT COALESCE(MAX([id]), 0)+1, 'aN', 'bN' FROM [t1];
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
```

Comment: Just curious, is it worth to bother with this longer version vs. what I updated in the original post? PS. Thanks for a nice addition about XACT_ABORT.

Comment: It's up to you. If you want to handle the error, or if you want to do more work in your batch after that particular transaction, I would opt for more explicit error handling as `XACT_ABORT` will terminate your batch on any error. In your case, I suspect `XACT_ABORT` is just fine.

Comment: WITHIN THE CATCH, I use `IF XACT_STATE()!=0 BEGIN ROLLBACK END` and I put the COMMIT within the `TRY` block

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sqlservertransactions.aspx

The above may give you an idea.

Comment: The examples of handling errors there are mostly based on stored procedures. Mine isn't...

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention your **version** of SQL Server - but starting with the 2005 version, you can use `BEGIN TRY... END TRY BEGIN CATCH... END CATCH` style exception handling.

I typically wrap my statement blocks in a transaction/try-catch block skeleton something like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY

    -- put your statements to be executed *HERE*    

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
        ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
        ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
        ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

That block tries to execute my statements - if it succeeds, the transaction is committed, if an exception happens, the execution jumps into the `CATCH` block, prints out detailed error info, and rolls back the transaction

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following method:

```
BEGIN TRY
   BEGIN TRANSACTION 
     DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id>1
     --- set of your querys 
    COMMIT
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH 
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  
       ROLLBACK 
END CATCH
```